# How can I Optimize my WordPress Blog?

Tags: wordpress, caching, optimization, performance

WordPress broke my server and i want to ask:

How can i optimizate or cache my wordpress blog?

Can i use some plugin like "WP Super Cache" or "W3 Total Cache" and which is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Hyper Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyper-cache/).

There are others. But from experience Hyper Cache is the easiest to install and provides immediate performance improvements. Don't take my word for it though, here's an excellent [comparison between several WordPress caching plugins](http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/web-tutorials/wordpress-caching-whats-the-best-caching-plugin/).

Comment: Is this plugin better than "WP Super Cache" or "W3 Total Cache"

Comment: From my experience, yes. See update.